# Why isn't my Bloc Listener listening to state changes during multiple emits in the same event?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Bloc Listener is not listening to the state changes during multiple emits in same event.

I am performing an async operation to fetch a list of upcoming trips from the repository. Before fetching i am emitting a loading state. After fetching I am emitting a success state along with the list.

Basically there are two emits in same event.
BLOC:

```dart
Future<void> _onTripsFetchUpcoming(TripsEvent event, Emitter emit) async {
    await tripsBlocTryCatchWrapper(() async {
      if (event is TripsFetchUpcoming) {
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            status: TripsStatus.fetchUpcomingTrips,
            loadingMessage: "Fetching upcoming trips.",
          ),
        );
        final res =
            await _tripsRepository.getAllUpcomingTrips(event.opId.toString());
            
        emit(
          state.copyWith(
            successMessage: "Successfully fetched all upcoming trips.",
            status: TripsStatus.fetchedUpcomingTrips,
            upcomingTrips: res,
          ),
        );
      }
    }, emit);
  }
```

I have setup a bloc listener in another widget to listen to these changes and trigger the ModalCubit which shows a modal. For testing I tried with a simple snack bar.

```dart
BlocListener<TripsBloc, TripsState>(
                    listenWhen: (previous, current) =>
                        previous.status != current.status,
                    listener: (context, tripsState) {
                      
                      print(tripsState.status);
                      if (tripsState.status.isLoading ||
                          tripsState.status.isFetchingUpcomingTrips) {
                        context.read<ModalCubit>().showModal(
                              ModalLoadingChild(
                                subject: "Trips",
                                message: tripsState.loadingMessage,
                              ),
                              "loading",
                              stopClose: true,
                            );
                      } else if (tripsState.status.isFetchedUpcomingTrips ||
                          tripsState.status.isSuccess) {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text(tripsState.status.toString())));
                        print("SUCCESSS");
                        //  context.read<ModalCubit>().hideModal();
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(tripsState.status.toString())));
                        context.read<ModalCubit>().showModal(
                              ModalSuccessChild(
                                subject: "Trips",
                                message: tripsState.successMessage,
                              ),
                              "success",
                            );
                      }
                    },
                  );
```

In the above listener, the loading state emit is being recognized by the listener but it is not picking up the second emit(Success).

Even in ModalCubit Listener only the loading state is shown and not the InActive State.

```dart
BlocListener<ModalCubit, ModalState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(state.toString())));
      },
)
```

#### EDIT 1.0

Any emit() after the await _tripsRepository.getAllUpcomingTrips(),  is not picked up by the `BlocListener`, this is the same case in all my blocs.

#### EDIT 1.1 - Adding the wrapper.

```dart
Future<void> tripsBlocTryCatchWrapper<T>(
    FutureOr<T> Function() tryBlock, void Function(TripsState) emit) async {
  try {
    await tryBlock();
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    emit(
      TripsError(
        message: e.error.toString(),
      ),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    emit(
      TripsError(
        message: "Something went wrong in profile.",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### EDIT 2.0:

I would like a solution to implement the bloc listener globally, when I tried with the individual home widget it worked, whereas when I set it as a direct child to MaterialApp, the issue is as described.

Comment: I hope you are using equatable props, can you recheck `props` if fails try adding `identityHashCode(this)` on props

Comment: I am using Equatable props, but there is a status variable which is an enum, is ir causing problem? But it shouldn't as there are two other values which are being changed along with it.

Comment: what does `tripsBlocTryCatchWrapper()` look like? Are you sure that the second `emit` is being called? Or perhaps there's an error being caught before that actually happend?

Comment: Thats a custom wrapper i created, but even without that its the same case. I will post the wrapper in an edit. @anqit

Comment: Ok, can you confirm that the second emit is actually being called, and no error is being thrown prior to that emit call that would prevent it from emitting? Either by stepping through it with a debugger, print statements, etc?

Comment: The second emit is actually updating the state, I ran it through debugger and also setup an observer. It’s just that the bloc listener isn’t picking up any state changes after the ‘await’.

Comment: the answers at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304754/flutter-blocconsumer-does-not-listen-to-the-state-passed-by-the-block) maybe help you

Comment: The implementation is different from mine, I used context.read to fire the event from home page, and indeed it is getting firef as I can see the transition and change via BlocObserver. But the state after the await is not picked up by BlocListener.

Comment: maybe put a breakpoint/log line in `listenWhen` and see if that is actually returning `true` after the second `emit`? If you can make a minimal reproduction as well, it could be easier to help debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i extracted the listener into a separate widget as used it as a wrapper to every single screen i need, then it will work. It is mostly getting removed from the widget tree somewhere after invocation.